# webpackで結合したファイルのサイズが6MBを超えてしまいます

Tags: angularjs, webpack, es6

webpack/es2015で開発をしているのですが、結合したファイルのサイズが6MBを超えてしまいます。
angular-materialのimportを外すと3MBほど減るのですが、それにしても大きすぎるのでなんとかしたいのですが、そもそもそのくらいのサイズになるのは仕方がないのでしょうか？

src

```
import 'babel-polyfill';

import angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-material';
```

webpack.config.js

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel?presets[]=es2015&plugins[]=add-module-exports', include: path.resolve('src')},
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: "style!css"
    },
    {
      test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
      loaders: [
        'style',
        'css?sourceMap&modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
        'sass'
      ]
    },
    {test: /\.(|jpg|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'},
    {
      test: [/fontawesome-webfont\.svg/, /fontawesome-webfont\.eot/, /fontawesome-webfont\.ttf/, /fontawesome-webfont\.woff/, /fontawesome-webfont\.woff2/],
      loader: 'file?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
    },
    {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'ng-cache?prefix=[dir]/[dir]'}
  ],
  preLoaders: [{test: /\.js$/, loader: 'eslint', include: path.resolve('src')}]
},
```